My Expo upgrade from 48 to 51 giving Problems
I am updating my expo project from expo 48 to expo 51 and I am getting same error again and again.
Error Image
And my package.json file after running,  npm install expo@latest and npx expo install --fix command
{
  "name": "BelCitiSolSmartLighting",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/pt-serif": "^0.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.7.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.3.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "axios-auth-refresh": "^3.2.2",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "expo": "~51.0.4",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.1",
    "expo-camera": "~15.0.7",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.1",
    "expo-crypto": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.4",
    "expo-intent-launcher": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-location": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~16.0.3",
    "expo-network": "~6.0.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~7.0.4",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-sharing": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.25.11",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "link": "^1.5.1",
    "material-icons": "^1.13.10",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "native-base": "^3.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.4",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-barcode-mask": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1284.0",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-indicator": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-maps": "1.14.0",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-modern-datepicker": "^1.0.0-beta.91",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.4",
    "react-native-popable": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.12",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-radio-buttons-group": "^3.0.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-redash": "^16.3.0",
    "react-native-root-siblings": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "recharts": "^2.1.9",
    "rn-tooltip": "^3.0.1",
    "safe-json-stringify": "^1.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.4",
    "victory-native": "^36.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.79",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.67.6",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.10",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "crypto-js": "3.1.9-1",
    "**/crypto-js": "3.1.9-1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assests/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}

Please provide me solution.
Also I unstalled one by one package to see what is problem but not getting solution

Have you build a new development application?

no @Thomasino73

Thats your problem i think. You need to create a new one.

Why I need to create?  npm install expo@51 and npx expo install --fix not solve my problem on existing project? @Thomsino73

You just did a major update which requires a rebuild. No, just adding --fix does not solve your problem.

I had the same problem as you!
Steps I did:
Add regenerator-runtime/runtime to the top of my index.js (root):
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

Added the babel-plugin-module-resolver as a dependency, in my case was missing:
  "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",

Added @babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from as a dev dependency:
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",

I think maybe only this will solve your problem.
For iOS I had to update my PodFile, removing Flipper and changing a few lines:
Usually on the podfile you have the lines by default on previous RN versions:
flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.disabled
if ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == '1' then
  # Explicitly disabled through environment variables
  flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.disabled
elsif podfile_properties.key?('ios.flipper') then
  # Configure Flipper in Podfile.properties.json
  if podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] == 'true' then
    flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug", "Release"])
  elsif podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] != 'false' then
    flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug", "Release"], { 'Flipper' => podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] })
  end
end

And then inside use_react_native:
  use_react_native!(
    (...)
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work if enabled
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config
  )

So basically you have to remove all of it.
For the latest React Native version, here's how an updated podfile looks:
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] = podfile_properties['newArchEnabled'] == 'true' ? '1' : '0'
ENV['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR'] = podfile_properties['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR']

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '14.0'
install! 'cocoapods',
  :deterministic_uuids => false

prepare_react_native_project!

target 'MyApp' do
  use_expo_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']
  use_frameworks! :linkage => ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS'].to_sym if ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == nil || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
    # Temporarily disable privacy file aggregation by default, until React
    # Native 0.74.2 is released with fixes.
    :privacy_file_aggregation_enabled => podfile_properties['apple.privacyManifestAggregationEnabled'] == 'true',
  )

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false,
      :ccache_enabled => podfile_properties['apple.ccacheEnabled'] == 'true',
    )

    # This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
    # when building for devices.
    installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
      .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
      target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
        resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end
end


Update packages
Also updated my packages to the latest version, following the Expo docs, for example all the @react-native-community, expo-*, types and firebase packages...
Let me know if this fixes your problem, in case I forgot something else.
Expo Prebuild command
In case you're not using managed Expo, you can run npx expo prebuild to generate all the native files again and check what is different. What I did was create a new branch, delete my ios and android folders, run prebuild, check with Git the difference between the newly generated and the old files. Since I have native modules and other libraries with configs on files such as appDelegate.mm and so on, I have to add it back because the prebuild removes it. But maybe this does not apply to your problem, is just a way of checking and removing problems.
